# how to bind the Data to Listbox asynchronously in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, performance, listbox

Currently I'm have around 2000 building data which is being loading in the `listbox` due to which the page loads slowly and I want load only i.e 10  building on `page load` so that page could load faster and other `UI` control could load faster.

tried:

For this I've added the result of grid in `session` so when the user clicks on the particular link in `grid` it does not hit the `SP/database` and get result from `session` but it does not help much.page 
loading still is slow

So is there any other way to load the `Listbox` faster ?
adding the code
code `.aspx`

```
<asp:ListBox ID="drpBuilding" runat="server" CssClass="formcontrol"SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
```

c# code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
            this.drpBuilding.Items.Clear();
    List<PResponse.BLL.Building> lstBuildings = default(List<PResponse.BLL.Building>);
    if (Session["buildinglist"] == null) {
    lstBuildings = this.mBuildingBLL.Get_ContactSiteBuildingsListLoad(p_ContactID: UserWrapper.GetCurrentUser().ContactID, p_ShowInactive: false);//SP method
                Session["buildinglist"] = lstBuildings;
            } else {
                lstBuildings = Session["buildinglist"]; //not hitting the SP/DB getting value from SP
            }
            if (lstBuildings.Count > 0) {
                this.drpBuilding.Enabled = true;
                this.drpBuilding.DataSource = lstBuildings;

            } else {
                this.drpBuilding.Enabled = false;
            }
            this.drpBuilding.DataTextField = "Building";
            this.drpBuilding.DataValueField = "BuildingID";
            this.drpBuilding.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify 2 things? 1) Listbox is loading 10 records at start, right? 2) What's in your grid when Listbox owns 10 records?

Comment: 1.yes 2.nothing grid will load only on search button click

Comment: Show your code, I don't fully understand.

Comment: done added the existing code @MAdeelKhalid

Comment: got it now ? @MAdeelKhalid